# Comparison in list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
list_a = [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (0, 1, 2, 4, 3), (0, 1, 3, 2, 4)]
```

I need a proper way to compare every single element of the tuples if they are greater than the other.

For example:

```
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4 )
```

Is `0 < 1 < 2 < 3 < 4` ?

It is not enough to find out if it's sorted. I need the explicit comparison of all elements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This `[0][0]<[0][1]<[0][2]<[0][3]<[0][4]` is not clear.

Comment: So you want to know if the list is sorted in lexicographic order?

Comment: So you want to check if every tuple is sorted? Please [edit] to clarify. See [ask] for advice. Posting your best attempt would also help.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon No, like I said in the edit, I need the explicit comparison.

Comment: @wjandrea No, like I said in the edit, I need the explicit comparison.

Comment: @DanRu Isn't that the same as checking if it's sorted? Maybe I'm missing some subtlety.

Comment: @DanRu I edited my answer, does it address your question now? If it does not, please specify the exact output format you expect.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon It's perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main concern here seems to be about how to iterate over consecutive pairs of elements in a sequence. The [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) can be helpful here as they provide a neat way to iterate over those pairs.

### Code for `pairwise_comparisons`

```
from itertools import tee

# From itertools recipes
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

# Return pairwise comparison results
def pairwise_comparisons(seq):
    return [x < y for x, y in pairwise(seq)]
```

### Example

```
list_a = [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (0, 1, 2, 4, 3), (0, 1, 3, 2, 4)]

for t in list_a:
    print(t, "comparisons:", pairwise_comparisons(t))
```

### Output

```
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4) comparisons: [True, True, True, True]
(0, 1, 2, 4, 3) comparisons: [True, True, True, False]
(0, 1, 3, 2, 4) comparisons: [True, True, False, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give you a list of list.

```
[[True if j>i[0] else False for j in i] for i in list_a]
```

This is comparison between the first item and all other items. If you want to compare adjacent values:

```
[[True if index >0 and j>i[index-1] else False for index,j in enumerate(i)] for i in list_a]
```